# Comparator.comparing with two arguments to the lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, comparator

I wrote my custom comparator in non java 8 way as below, but not clear even after reading some blogs, how to do it using `Comparator.comparing` with the `lambda` style syntax.

```
class MyCustomComparator  implements Comparator<Integer> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer n1, Integer n2) {
        String ns1 = Integer.toString(n1) + Integer.toString(n2);
        String ns2 = Integer.toString(n2) + Integer.toString(n1);
        if (Integer.parseInt(ns1) > Integer.parseInt(ns2)) {
            return 1;
        } else if (Integer.parseInt(ns1) < Integer.parseInt(ns2))
            return -1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Generally `Comparator.comparing` takes the lambda where most examples I say the lamda is not taking argument.

Comment: Can you guarantee that `ns1` and `ns2` can be parsed as integers? (they might not if e.g. at least one is negative, or the concatenated numbers are bigger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`)

Comment: Note: `return Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(ns1), Integer.parseInt(ns2);` is easier.

Comment: @Pshemo, I understand that part. Hence, my Q to be more specific and clear on it was to know if Java 8 allows me to pass 2 arguments to my Lambda i.e does comparing method allow me to give a lambda that can take 2 args. I guess not.

Comment: In reality, `ns1` and `ns2` will always be same length, and method will fail for negative numbers, so we don't need to support that, we can conclude that a simply string comparison of `ns1` and `ns2` will provide the same result, so to use shorthand code, method in question is same as `return ("" + n1 + n2).compareTo("" + n2 + n1);`, except that it won't fail on bad input.

Comment: @curiousengineer The `comparing()` method does't allow a lambda taking two arguments, because that's not the purpose of it. The purpose is for it to apply a mapping function (the lambda) to each of the two objects being compared, before calling `a.compareTo(b)` on the mapped objects. By nature, the mapping function takes one object as argument and returns another object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Comparator.comparing` allows you to specify a transformation to be applied to each object individually before comparing them. Since your Comparator requires both arguments in order to apply its logic, you cannot write it as a `Comparator.comparing` expression.

Comment: Thanks for confirming it. I was also assuming the same but was not sure if it was my lack of knowledge. Scala allows much doing these things in a much easier way.

Comment: @curiousengineer Well, somewhat easier would be to replace the content of the method with a single statement: `return Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(n1) + Integer.toString(n2)), Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(n2) + Integer.toString(n1)));`

Answer (score 3):

The `Comparator.comparing…` factory methods are suitable for creating comparators comparing transformed values or properties of the elements to compare, but not when you have to combine both values.

But you can still implement you comparator using a lambda expression without the factory method

```
Comparator<Integer> myCustomComparator = (n1, n2) -> {
    String ns1 = "" + n1 + n2, ns2 = "" + n2 + n1;
    return Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(ns1), Integer.parseInt(ns2));
};
```